# Can't Change the Calendar Visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an image button which should toggle the calendar whose visibility is set to false initially.
This is the Page_Load Code:

```
Calendar3.EnableViewState = false;

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindData();
}
```

This is on imagebutton click.

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
     if (Calendar3.Visible == false)
         Calendar3.Visible = true;
     else
         Calendar3.Visible = false;
 }
```

The calendar becomes visible on the first click and I can't hide it if I click on the button again. How can I change visibility property of calendar control work on every button click.

PS: I'm using the calendar control and the imagebutton inside an update panel to take of postback and when I try to debug, the visibility property is set to default value from the calendar tag on every page_load.

Thanks

Comment: Remove this line - `Calendar3.EnableViewState = false;`

Comment: @avd : toggle works..but when i select the same date again..the calendar is not disappearing .... how can i do that...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
Calendar3.EnableViewState = false;
```

and you can simply write the button click event as:

```
Calendar3.Visible = !Calendar3.Visible; //toggle effect
```

Comment: it works, but how do i handle the visibility when i select the same date. that line of code is used when select the same date.

Comment: i'm using this calendar load function during selecting the same date, but toggle function not working now.what else can be done..??

Comment: @sandy, when you are selecting the same date, selected index change is not getting fired, since there is no change.

Comment: @so how do i handle that along with maintaining the toggle effect..??? 
thanks....

Comment: @sandy,that itself is a probably a new question with respect to Calendar control, I am not sure if there is a mouse click event for Calendar control, you may have to resolve to client side scripting

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a client side event to changes the visibility of the Calender Control instead of using sever side event.

Eg.:

Set style="display:none" initailly & the toggle it using client side event (**using jQuery**).

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("<%=Calendar3.ClientID%>").css("display", "none");
        $("<%=ImageButton1.ClientID%>").on("click", function(){
         $("<%=Calendar3.ClientID%>").toggle();
        });
    });
<\script>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment...actually needed a server side event to handle out the property..thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Calendar3.Visible returns a bool so no need of

`if (Calendar3.Visible == false)`

just

```
if (!Calendar3.Visible)
```

will do